# Unable to drag-and-drop files into other applications on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm able to drag-and-drop files from one folder into another folder through the native Files app. However, I'm unable to drag-and-drop files from the Files app into third-party programs (eg, Chrome and VS Code).

I'm able to select files in third-party programs by opening the file modal. Drag-and-drop just doesn't work.

I suspect that it's a permissions issue where these third-party programs aren't authorized to accept these files. I don't know how to validate this theory.

edit: It works on Firefox, which came pre-installed with ubuntu.

```bash
> lsb_release -a

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

```bash
> stat --format '%a' /usr/bin/google-chrome

777
```

```bash
> stat --format '%a' /snap/bin/firefox

777
```

Comment: Is the software you mentioned (Chrome, VS Code) installed from the official repos or are they snaps/flatpaks (shouldn't matter, but who knows)?

Comment: I installed from `.deb` files downloaded from their respective websites.

Comment: Are those two programs the only ones where this happens? What happens if you try to drag-and-drop into applications you've installed from the official repos? Having Ubuntu, I assume you can drag-and-drop from the file manager into Firefox (if you have it installed)?

Comment: Interesting. Drag-and-drop works on Firefox (which came pre-bundled with Ubuntu).

Comment: What happens if you `stat --format '%a' path/to/executable` on Chrome first, and then the same command on a different executable in the same folder right after (e.g. Firefox)? Edit the post and paste the output.

Comment: Updated. Looks like Firefox is a snap package, whereas Chrome is just in `/usr/bin`. Can that be the cause?

Answer (score 4):

It is a permission issue/feature with Ubuntu 22.04.

Opening folders with `sudo nautilus /home/user/` or `sudo xdg-open /home/user/` fixes this.

Comment: OK I can confirm this works for me (allows drag and drop from nautilus to Chrome) but...why? And since I don't particularly feel like granting nautilus root permissions all the time, is there a way to solve this more formally?

Comment: Good question, it seems the be a security measure between applications. You need to disable Wayland and enable X.org. Follow these steps open: `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` change `WaylandEnable=true` to `WaylandEnable=false` and then save the changes. After this `sudo systemctl restart gdm3`.

Comment: Thanks - switching display servers would do it. I would like to avoid discarding all of Wayland over this and finding a solution within Wayland. Thank you for the info nonetheless.

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks! This should be the official answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using Wayland. Try to log in using X.Org instead.

To do so: log out or reboot your PC, when you come to welcome screen, there should be a cog in the lower right corner. Click on that, and select "Ubuntu on Xorg".

See if it persists.

Comment: I have a gtkmm application where I drag and drop on a popover. I have the same problem described in this post. Running the app as admin solves the problem. Not using Wayland as you suggested also fixes the problem. Is there a solution to the issue without running things as admin and using Wayland?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 22.xx? If so, you might want to check this out: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1970921

Comment: The problem is present when using Wayland with Ubuntu 22.04 and 22.10. I can drag and drop between instance windows of the application, but cannot drag and drop to a popover of the application. I am guessing it is a gtk issue,  I made a post in the Gnome forum: [ubuntu-22-04-with-wayland-prevents-gtkmm-drag-and-drop-to-popover](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/ubuntu-22-04-with-wayland-prevents-gtkmm-drag-and-drop-to-popover/14005)

Comment: By the same argument, I could avoid this issue by using Mac OS or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**[0xheartcode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/547864/0xheartcode)** mentioned the solution in comments above.  The only difference in mine was the **'WaylandEnable=false'** **was commented out**.

Once I did the following, I could drag and drop files from the host to the VM's File Manager and the file copied.  (I'm also using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTM.)

> Good question, it seems the be a security measure between applications. You need to disable Wayland and enable X.org. Follow these steps...

1. **sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf**
2. Uncomment **'#WaylandEnable=false'** by removing the **'#'** (and/or change =true to =false)
3. **sudo systemctl restart gdm3**

Answer (score 0):

I use this way to solve the problem.You have to put files by pressing windows + right like this.

Note when you select a file you have to click on the application you want to move first, then click alt + tab and only then can you drag and drop

[image]